# Give the posts in a category an incremental number value as custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I want every post in one category to have an incremental number value based on the time it was created.

So in category A, the first post has number 1 as custom field value, second number 2 etc.
If i create a post in category B, then it also has value 1, if i post afterwards a post in category C, it also has value 1.

Is this clear? :)

I found this snippet, but it doesn't take in account the category issue.

```
function updateNumbers() {
/* numbering the published posts: preparation: create an array with the ID in sequence of publication date, /
/ save the number in custom field 'incr_number' of post with ID /
/ to show in post (within the loop) use <?php echo get_post_meta($post-   >ID,'incr_number',true); ?>
/ alchymyth 2010 */
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$counts = 0 ;
if ($pageposts):
foreach ($pageposts as $post):
setup_postdata($post);
$counts++;
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts, true);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts);
endforeach;
endif;
}
add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'deleted_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'edit_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use is_category() or something like that inside the foreach? find if posts are same cat, then add the number, find some other cat/posts, add number again...

first thing comes to mind.